# Confusion configuring silverstripe advancedworkflow workflow

Tags: module, content-management-system, silverstripe

I'm assessing the advancedworkflow module (version 3.0.2) for the first time, in a fresh Silverstripe 3.1.5 installation.

Initially, I tried setting up a custom workflow but struggled to get it working, so I decided to start with the single-action 'Publish' workflow, and then incrementally enhance and test the workflow until it matched the intended target, but have quickly hit a point of confusion.

The basic configuration (new account - can't post an image!), which doesn't even reassign to another user group action, is as follows:

1. SimpleApprovalWorkflowAction: 'Approve Publication'
   --> Transition: 'approve' -> Publish
   --> Transition: 'reject' -> Reject Publication
2. PublishItemWorkflowAction: 'Publish'
3. CancelWorkflowAction: 'Reject Publication'

so the sequence for the initiator should (?) just be:

1. (make change / save draft)
2. Approve Publication
3. Publish

However, when, after making the initial change and clicking 'Approve Publication', the page remains in a draft state but there is no second step to actually 'Publish' the page. (In a later refinement of the workflow, this is intended to be done by a different user group, and so separated by an 'Assign to users' action.)

Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

This user help article might help with this http://userhelp.silverstripe.org/framework/en/for-website-administrators/setting-up-advancedworkflow

A good idea is to flow diagram out the workflow you want before setting up the actions and transitions in the module.